# How to append variables to an array in google scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

Right now I'm working on a project and I need to append a certain variable to an array. What I need to do is to read values from a spreadsheet and extract values that meet a certain criterion.

In mathematica I will do it like this

```
If[IFin="RECIBIDO", 
(*If true, do nothing*), 
(*else*) AppendTo[pendientes,{"project#", "IFin", IFin}]
]
```

But I need to apply it in a google sheets script, so right now I'm trying this (I'm using a switch case structure because of my needs)

```
var IFin=0 //it can take the following values 0, 1, 2, 3, "RECIBIDO"
var pendientes=[]; 
var InfOK = "RECIBIDO";

switch(IFin){
      case InfOk:
           break;
      case 0:
           [i,"IFin",IFin].appendTo(pendientes); 
           break;
      case 1:
           [i,"IFin",IFin].appendTo(pendientes); 
           break;
      case 2:
           [i,"IFin",IFin].appendTo(pendientes); 
           break;
      case 3:
           [i,"IFin",IFin].appendTo(pendientes); 
           break;
}
```

And all it says when I try to run it is "TypeError: Could not find funcion appendTo". I'm new to google scripts, and hence I'm using this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_appendto.asp I've searched the google help and it has an extensive explanation of sheets functions.

---

**Solution**

This made me understand the root of the problem but proposed solution hasn't been tested yet:

> appendTo isn't an array method in javascript. You could do something
>   like pendientes = pendientes.concat([i,"IFin",IFIN])

This helped me solve the problem:

> Try using push(). This method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

So by replacing

```
[i,"IFin",IFin].appendTo(pendientes);
```

by

```
pendientes.push([i,"IFin",IFin]);
```

my code worked just fine.

Comment: `appendTo` isn't an array method in javascript. You could do something like `pendientes = pendientes.concat([i,"IFin",IFIN])`

Comment: Welcome. To ask question like "why this code isn't working", askers should include a [mcve]. Please follow [tour] and checkout [ask].

Comment: Try using [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=example). This method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array. As also suggested in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313639/how-to-append-array-data-to-spreadsheet-column-at-once-using-google-script), you can first create a new array then append the values as arrays with one value.

Comment: Hi everyone! Thanks for helping! Using the push method worked just fine!